# Two routers with the same MAC address

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, security, remote-access

I have had some security issues in the past - someone specific targeting my network. I used Advanced IP scanner and found 2 devices connected, both displaying as routers (one of them I recognise, because it has the correct manufacturer name) and the other is one I don`t recognise (it is titled MYROUTER).

The two "routers" have the same MAC address, but different IPs. None of the devices that I have connected to the network myself have this IP. Should I be worried? Is this possible? What`s going on?

Comment: Why not physically hunt the device down and have a look what it is?

Comment: While I cannot comment on your specific situation, it is definitely possible to have a device with a spoofed MAC address as your router, and that way the device (can intercept all traffic going to the router.)

Comment: @Seth, how can you physically locate a device, for instance, on a Wi-Fi network?

Comment: @Seth, how can you physically locate a device, for instance, on a Wi-Fi network?

Exactly... I can`t find this device, physically. That`s why I`m worried that it may be a device that is intercepting my traffic...

Comment: So that is not really normal, right? To have two routers on the device list, with the same MAC and different IPs? 
Would something catastrophic happen to my network if I disable the other one?

Comment: While it does have the tag wireless network it not clear whenever the other device is connected through it. In addition the wireless aspect is missing from the question itself. It is unusual but could be normal. If you're worried that someone is sniffing your network you should make sure that you're using a strong encryption and in doubt exchange the keys. Furthermore you could deliberately connect to that router to figure out more about it (e.g. by visiting a "what is my ip" service and comparing it against your actual internet IP. This could be dangerous for your system though.

Comment: I don`t know whether it`s tagged a wireless network, because IP Scanner gives no other information other than its IP & MAC address. For the other devices it gives manufacturer details, but this one is just empty.

Comment: A network interface can have any number of IP addresses assigned. So that’s normal. A true MAC address conflict would quickly manifest in strange network behavior. So the question is how you determined the apparent “MYROUTER” device name.

Comment: If they have he same mac address, they would have the same IP. Sounds/feels a lot like a misconfiguration or something odd. Could you do a nmap/zenmap scan (quick scan plus would do) - I'd specifically be looking for what ports/services are open, and the OS identification. And possibly what the possible attacker has one in the past I suppose.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek “If they have he same mac address, they would have the same IP.” – Not necessarily. Like I mentioned in my comment, any number of IP addresses can be “backed” by the same MAC address. The other way around (IP address conflict) is what’s “not possible”.

Comment: ah. My bad. The rest of my comment might be handy tho.

Comment: I'll bet your IP scanner tool uses more than one discovery protocol to scan the network, and that your router happens to show up two different ways via two different protocols. For example, one of the IP addresses might be an IPv4 or IPv6 link-local address, whereas the other is your router's RFC1918 private IP address.

Comment: Try unplugging stuff until it disappears...

Answer (score 1):

One of the method to attack a wireless network is to make a router or a wireless adapter have the same mac address of your router and the same channel + the same SSID "the name of your network"

When the attacker start, you will feel your network very slow then your router will restart, now all the devices on your network will be connected to his device, all your devices will send a handshake "packet with the password encrypted" to his device.

There is no reason for him to use the same MAC address after that, in some additional attacks he need the same mac address just to sniff your packets and know exactly what happening inside network.

Or maybe he forget to change the MAC address!
Sometimes I found weird names inside my network it's not always an attack! other network can interfere with your network, if you want to know for real what he is doing check the data transferred for that device! if he sniffing! or just an interfere.

If he is really an attacker and want's to know his physical address check for apps like this one on your mobile and follow the signal strength ;)

[image]